# Everything inside jQuery.ajax({ success:

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

First of all , I apologize - my English is bad .

Is it a bad approach to put all the main code inside success setting  ($.ajax({ success: ) - for example, I have this JSON in file mydata.json:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Aster",
        "product": "aster",
        "stock": "10",
        "price": "2.99"
    },
    {
        "name": "Daffodil",
        "product": "daffodil",
        "stock": "10",
        "price": "1.99"
    },
    {
        "name": "Rose",
        "product": "rose",
        "stock": "2",
        "price": "4.99"
    },
    {
        "name": "Peony",
        "product": "peony",
        "stock": "3",
        "price": "1.50"
    },
    {
        "name": "Primula",
        "product": "primula",
        "stock": "20",
        "price": "3.12"
    },
    {
        "name": "Snowdrop",
        "product": "snowdrop",
        "stock": "5",
        "price": "0.99"
    },
    {
        "name": "Carnation",
        "product": "carnation",
        "stock": "1",
        "price": "0.50"
    },
    {
        "name": "Lily",
        "product": "lily",
        "stock": "2",
        "price": "1.20"
    },
    {
        "name": "Orchid",
        "product": "orchid",
        "stock": "5",
        "price": "10.99"
    }
]
```

And, my code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "mydata.json",
    success: function (data) {
        var html = '';
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            html += '<div class="dcell">';
            html += '<img src="images/' + value.product + '.png">';
            html += '<label for="' + value.product + '">' + value.name + ':</label>';
            html += '<input id="' + value.product + '" type="text" required="" value="0" name="' + value.product + '" stock="' + value.stock + '">'
            html += '</div>';
        });
        $(html).filter("div").slice(0, 3).appendTo("#drow1");
        $(html).filter("div").slice(3, 6).appendTo("#drow2");
        $(html).filter("div").slice(6).appendTo("#drow3");

        $("<div id='errorContainer'>Odgovor...:</div>")
            .addClass("inputGreska").append("<ul id='errorLabelContainer'></ul>").hide().insertAfter("h1");

        $("form").validate({
            highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
                $(element).addClass("invalidElem");
            },
            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
                $(element).removeClass("invalidElem");
            },
            errorContainer: "#errorContainer",
            errorLabelContainer: "#errorLabelContainer",
            wrapper: "li",
            errorElement: "div"
        });

        var plurals = {
            aster: "Asters",
            daffodil: "Daffodils",
            rose: "Roses",
            peony: "Peonies",
            primula: "Primulas",
            snowdrop: "Snowdrops",
            carnation: "Carnations",
            lily: "Lillies",
            orchid: "Orchids"
        }

        $("input").each(function (index, elem) {
            $(elem).rules("add", {
                required: true,
                min: 0,
                digits: true,
                messages: {
                    required: "Please enter a number of " + plurals[elem.name],
                    digits: "Please enter a number of " + plurals[elem.name],
                    min: "Please enter a positive number of " + plurals[elem.name]
                }
            })
        }).change(function (e) {
            $("form").validate().element($(e.target));
        });


        $("#drow2, #drow3").hide();

        $("<a id='left'></a>").prependTo("#oblock").css({
            "background-image": "url(images/leftarrows.png)",
                "display": "block",
                "float": "left",
                "width": "50px",
                "height": "50px",
                "margin-top": "15px"
        }).hover(handleMouseEnter).click(handleMouseClick);
        $("<a id='right'></a>").appendTo("#oblock").css({
            "background-image": "url(images/rightarrows.png)",
                "display": "block",
                "float": "right",
                "width": "50px",
                "height": "50px",
                "margin-top": "15px"
        }).hover(handleMouseEnter).click(handleMouseClick);

        function handleMouseEnter(e) {
            if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
                $(this).css({
                    "background-position": "-50px 0px",
                        "cursor": "pointer"
                });
            } else {
                $(this).css({
                    "background-position": "0px 0px"
                });
            }
        }

        function handleMouseClick(e) {
            var redovi = ["drow1", "drow2", "drow3"];
            var trenutniRed = $("div.drow:visible");
            var indexTrenutnogReda = jQuery.inArray(trenutniRed.attr("id"), redovi);
            var indexNovogReda;
            if ($(this).attr("id") == "left") {
                indexNovogReda = indexTrenutnogReda - 1;
                if (indexNovogReda < 0) {
                    indexNovogReda = redovi.length - 1;
                }
            } else {
                indexNovogReda = (indexTrenutnogReda + 1) % redovi.length;
            }
            trenutniRed.fadeOut("fast", function () {
                $("#" + redovi[indexNovogReda]).fadeIn("fast");
            });
        }

        $("#buttonDiv").prepend("<div>Total Items: <span id='total'>0</span></div>");
        $("input").change(function (e) {
            $("form").validate().element($(e.target));
            var total = 0;
            $("input").each(function (index, value) {
                total += Number($(value).val());
            });
            $("#total").text(total);
        })
    }
})
```

As you can see - everything is in the `success` property of `jQuery.ajax()`.

For this particular example, I know it can be done in a different way so that there is NOT almost everything inside `success` - but, does it make any difference? Or, it does not matter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would certainly extract the logic out of that huge block in to several functions which each complete one task. It won't help with performance, but will make maintenance easier. It'll also mean that the poor guy who has to maintain this code after you won't hunt you down and kill you. As this is working code though I would suggest you ask this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes, it's bad. In terms of readability and manageability it's horrendous. But at least you're asking the right questions. You aren't, however, asking it in the right place I'm afraid. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for advice on overall approaches to what code you already have.

Comment: One problem with your code is that when you read it is as foreigner, you can be sure without looking closer that the last `})`  belongs to your `$.ajax({`. Beside some exception you should try to make sure that corresponding `{`  `}`  are visible on screen. Instead of using an anonymous function as callback, you could define it _outside_  of your  `$.ajax` with a meaningful  name and then just do: `$.ajax({ url: "mydata.json", success: theMeaningFullName})` this for sure will not help with that large block of code, but you could step by step split your code in smaller chunks that way.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! So, If I understand correctly, the reasons why I should not do in this way (put everything in success: setting of $.ajax) are: 1) readability and manageability 2) If the code is ONLY supposed to run when the ajax returns successfully then it is probably ok. Otherwise, NO.

Comment: Yes the main reason is readability and maintainability. If you need to scroll multiple line up or down to determine in which block your are, then your `function`,  `if` clause, loop, .. might be to long and should be shortened. If the code you show is the only code in the file, then putting everything in the success callback could be ok. Many libraries use one large function to containing all the code to encapsulate the code, to e.g. prevent the pollution of the global scope and/or to _protect_ the used functions.